# ExecutorService.submit(<callable>) taking more time?

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

I am trying to understand the utilities in `java.util.concurrent` package and learnt that we can submit `callable` objects to the `ExecutorService`, which returns `Future`, which is filled with the value returned by the `callable`, after successful completion of task within `call()` method.

I am understanding that all the callables are executed concurrently using multiple threads.

When I wanted to see how much improvement `ExecutorService` gives over the batch task execution, i thought of capturing time.

Following is the code which i tried to execute -

```
package concurrency;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;


public class ExecutorExample {

    private static Callable<String> callable = new Callable<String>() {

        @Override
        public String call() throws Exception {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
                builder.append(i);
            }
            return builder.toString();
        }
    };

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        List<Future<String>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<String>>();
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
            Future<String> value = service.submit(callable);
            futures.add(value);
        }
        for(Future<String> f : futures) {
            try {
                System.out.println(f.isDone() + " " + f.get());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        long end  = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Executer callable time - " + (end - start));
        service.shutdown();

        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            for(int j=0; j<5; j++) {
                builder.append(j);
            }
            System.out.println(builder.toString());
        }
        end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Normal time - " + (end - start));
    }

}
```

and here is the output of this -

```
true 01234
true 01234
true 01234
true 01234
true 01234
Executer callable time - 5
01234
01234
01234
01234
01234
Normal time - 0
```

Please let me know if I am missing something OR understanding something in a wrong way.

Thanks in advance for your time and help for this thread.

Comment: What you are doing wrong is that this "benchmark" is _waaay_ too small to exploit the benefits of using multiple threads to do the job. Try something that takes time. Like computing the first 10000 primes, or something like that on each thread... Also, at the same time: you don't do any "warmup" iterations: the JVM might need to do some things when it first executes a given block of code, so you should do a few iterations that do not count into the final result...

Comment: @ppeterka thanks for your comment. However I did try "Runnable" instead of "Callable" (ExecutorService.submit(<runnable>) with the same task. And I saw improvement in the time consumption of the overall task. Runnable took 0 milliseconds difference. Hence i thought of asking this question.

Comment: Was the test with the "Runnable" executed after the test with "Callable" in the same JVM execution? And how do the numbers compare if you do 10000 iterations in the loop? Measuring time in this range is problematic at best...

Comment: Yes the main method had callable, runnable and normal execution

Comment: read my first comment's second half: you **must** have warmup iterations that are not measured in any way. The JVM needs to do some initialization, that take significant time only for the first time a specific part of a code runs. Copy the contents of the main method 2 times after each other to see what I mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you task in Callable is to small, you won't get benefits from concurrency due task switching and overhead for initialisation. Try to add more heavier loop in callable, say 1000000 iterations, and you can see difference

Answer (score 2):

When you run any code esp for the first time, it takes time.  If you pass a task to another thread it can take 1-10 micro-seconds and if your task take less time than this, the overhead can be greater than the benefit. i.e. using multiple threads can be much slower than using a single thread if your overhead is high enough.

I suggest you

- increase the cost of the task to 1000 iterations.
- make sure the result is not discarded in the single threaded example
- run both tests for at least a couple of seconds to ensure the code has warmed up.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer (but I am not sure the code will fit a comment). To expand a bit on what Peter said, there is usually a sweet spot for the size of your jobs (measured in execution time), to balance pool/queue overhead with fair work distribution among workers. The code example helps find an estimate for that sweet spot. Run on your target hardware.

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.*;

public class FibonacciFork extends RecursiveTask<Long> {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public FibonacciFork( long n) {
    super();
    this.n = n;
}

static ForkJoinPool fjp = new ForkJoinPool( Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());

static long fibonacci0( long n) {
    if ( n < 2) {
        return n;
    }
    return fibonacci0( n - 1) + fibonacci0( n - 2);
}

static int  rekLimit = 8;

private static long stealCount;

long    n;

private long forkCount;

private static AtomicLong forks = new AtomicLong( 0);

public static void main( String[] args) {

    int n = 45;
    long    times[] = getSingleThreadNanos( n);
    System.out.println( "Single Thread Times complete");
    for ( int r = 2;  r <= n;  r++) {
        runWithRecursionLimit( r, n, times[ r]);
    }
}

private static long[] getSingleThreadNanos( int n) {
    final long times[] = new long[ n + 1];
    ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( Math.max( 1, Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() / 2));
    for ( int i = 2;  i <= n;  i++) {
        final int arg = i;
        Runnable runner = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                long    start = System.nanoTime();
                final int minRuntime = 1000000000;
                long    runUntil = start + minRuntime;
                long    result = fibonacci0( arg);
                long    end = System.nanoTime();
                int         ntimes = Math.max( 1, ( int) ( minRuntime / ( end - start)));
                if ( ntimes > 1) {
                    start = System.nanoTime();
                    for ( int i = 0;  i < ntimes;  i++) {
                        result = fibonacci0( arg);
                    }
                    end = System.nanoTime();
                }
                times[ arg] = ( end - start) / ntimes;
            }
        };
        es.execute( runner);
    }
    es.shutdown();
    try {
        es.awaitTermination( 1, TimeUnit.HOURS);
    } catch ( InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println( "Single Timeout");
    }
    return times;
}

private static void runWithRecursionLimit( int r, int arg, long singleThreadNanos) {
    rekLimit = r;
    long    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long    result = fibonacci( arg);
    long    end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    // Steals zählen
    long    currentSteals = fjp.getStealCount();
    long    newSteals = currentSteals - stealCount;
    stealCount = currentSteals;
    long    forksCount = forks.getAndSet( 0);
    System.out.println( "Fib(" + arg + ")=" + result + " in " + ( end-start) + "ms, recursion limit: " + r +
            " at " + ( singleThreadNanos / 1e6) + "ms, steals: " + newSteals + " forks " + forksCount);
}

static long fibonacci( final long arg) {
    FibonacciFork   task = new FibonacciFork( arg);
    long result = fjp.invoke( task);
    forks.set( task.forkCount);
    return result;
}

@Override
protected Long compute() {
    if ( n <= rekLimit) {
        return fibonacci0( n);
    }
    FibonacciFork   ff1 = new FibonacciFork( n-1);
    FibonacciFork   ff2 = new FibonacciFork( n-2);
    ff1.fork();
    long    r2 = ff2.compute();
    long    r1 = ff1.join();
    forkCount = ff2.forkCount + ff1.forkCount + 1;
    return r1 + r2;
}
}
```